# Julia: Streaming transformations of IO/file data

Tags: io, julia

It seems to be a simple question, but I’m not able to figure out how to do it in Julia. We receive text files, but they have ‘\01’ or ‘\00’ as newline. The files are partially large (~10 GB) which is why we’d like to open a stream for file content, map ‘\01’ to ‘\r’ and then continue reading the lines. Something like (pseudo code):

```
open("myfile.dat", read=true) do fd
    fd = replace(fd, '\01' => '\r')
    for line in eachline(fd)
        ...
    end
end
```

Preferably it should work with input from files, cmds and IOBuffer.

I know we could invoke an external command to do the translation, but we are using Windows as well as Linux, and we’d like an approach that easily works on both.

Given this is a a concret use cases, we are wondering how IO stream processing generally works in Julia. Is there anything available already that is easy to use?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

If `'\01'` is the only delimiter, you can user [`readuntil`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.readuntil):

```
open("foo.txt"; read=true) do fd
    while !eof(fd)
        x = readuntil(fd, '\01')
        @show x
    end
end
```

If you have multiple delimiters, you can use a modified version of [Julia's `readuntil`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/f9720dc2ebd6cd9e3086365f281e62506444ef37/base/io.jl#L771):

```
function multireaduntil(s::IO, delims::Vector{<:AbstractChar}; keep::Bool=false)
    out = IOBuffer()
    for c in readeach(s, Char)
        if c in delims
            keep && write(out, c)
            break
        end
        write(out, c)
    end
    return String(take!(out))
end
```

which you can use like this:

```
open("foo.txt"; read=true) do fd
    while !eof(fd)
        x = multireaduntil(fd, ['\00', '\01'])
        @show x
    end
end
```

If you need more advanced parsing, I would suggest using something like [TextParse.jl](https://github.com/queryverse/TextParse.jl)

Comment: This is not really streaming, is it? In my pseudo code above you see that the output of 'replace' can be treated exactly like a file (IOBuffer). In your example you are returning blocks of data and all of the standard methods to process file content are no longer available.